# java && on if statement is not working

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean-logic

I'm using this code to enable a button when both fields are filled in and disable it when they aren't:

```
if (jTextFieldAccountName.getText().isEmpty() &&
    jPasswordFieldAccountPassword.getPassword().length == 0) {
    jButton_Next.setEnabled(false);
} else {
    jButton_Next.setEnabled(true);
}
```

But the button is enabled even if I type in only one of the fields. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your statement is working fine. The way you have it written, the button is going to be disabled only when BOTH fields are empty (if `jTextFieldAccountName` is empty AND `jPasswordFieldAccountPassword` length equals 0). When you type something into the first field, both fields are no longer empty so the condition sets false, and your button is enabled.

If you want both fields to be input before the button is enabled, change your logic to:

```
if ((!jTextFieldAccountName.getText().isEmpty()) && (jPasswordFieldAccountPassword.getPassword().length > 0)) {
            jButton_Next.setEnabled(true);
        }
        else {
            jButton_Next.setEnabled(false);
        }
```

If you use this logic, you can also set your password to be a minimum length (e.g. password > 6, or something like that).

Comment: hello it's working thanks but when i try this... both textfield and password is empty and button is already disabled... when I type to textfield the button still disabled then type on password the button is still disabled... it only enabled when I try to add 1 character on textfield so that the button will be enabled...

Comment: Right. The logic above will enable the button only when you have data in the account name & password field.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to use the OR logical operator i.e. `||`:

If (text-box-is-empty OR password-is-too-small) THEN...

Then try this code:

```
if ( jTextFieldAccountName.getText().isEmpty()
     || jPasswordFieldAccountPassword.getPassword().length < 6 )
{
    jButton_Next.setEnabled(false);
} else {
    jButton_Next.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Note I also changed the password-condition as passwords should be a minimal of 6 characters.